# Can't figure out batch input/output

Tags: batch-file

So, what I'm trying to do is make it to where the user can not delete batch files.

```
echo !Choose a file to delete:
set /p deletei=$_
DEL /P %deletei%
if %deletei% == %deletei%.bat goto $DELETEN

echo Access denied. You may not delete BATCH files.
pause > nul
```

It asks me "Would you like to delete this file? (Y/N)" Like any other, and if I type "Y", it deletes it. Is there any way around it?

Comment: On the next line of your batch file can you not just put a `Y`?

Comment: Why not check the filename BEFORE you run the delete command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SomethingDark subtly suggested, you need to check if it is a bat file before you delete

```
echo !Choose a file to delete:
set /p deletei=$_
if "%deletei:~-4%" NEQ ".bat" (
DEL /P %deletei%
) else (
echo Access denied. You may not delete BATCH files.
pause > nul
)
```

Which should check if the file is `.bat` before deleting.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great, @Monacraft. I'm still relatively new to Batch programming, so I was kind of confused as to what to do past this point.